# Why does this line of code not work?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
index = temp.indexOf(" \"");
```

This line of code is supposed to put index in the position of " but instead index = -1

```
temp = /path/to/image.jpg “Title text”)
```

Here is the whole method
index = line.indexOf("![");

```
            if (index > -1)
            {
                working = line.substring(0,index);
                String temp = line.substring(index+2,line.length());
                index = temp.indexOf("](");
                String altText = temp.substring(0, index);

                System.out.println(temp);

                temp = temp.substring(index+2, temp.length());

                System.out.println(temp);

                index = temp.indexOf(" \"");

                System.out.println(index);

                String imgPath = temp.substring(0, index);
                temp = temp.substring(index+2, line.length());
                index = temp.indexOf("\")");
                String titleText = temp.substring(0,index);
                temp = temp.substring(index+2, line.length());
                working = working + translateImage(altText, imgPath, titleText);
                working = working + temp;
                line = working;
                working = "";
            }
```

This is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
alternate text](/path/to/image.jpg “Title text”)
/path/to/image.jpg “Title text”)
-1
    at MarkdownTranslator.main(MarkdownTranslator.java:105)
```

I was using the strings after the exception for checking the values of the following variables respectively.
temp
temp
index

Comment: Can you post an example program that shows this behavior using a hard-coded String?

Comment: First of all, it would put the index at the position of the space before the double quote. And the example string you posted uses smart (or curly) quotes. Not regular quotes. Just look at what it looks like in the first code snippet in your question and in the second one. They're not the same character.

Answer (score 2):

If the second line of code is a Copy&Pasted version of the string, then it looks like the string actually contains "smart quotes".  These are not equivalent to the `'"'` character.

See the following:

- [**" Ascii 0x22 Double Quote**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm)
- [**“ Unicode U+201C Left Double Quote**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)
- [**” Unicode U+201D Right Double Quote**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)